# OGR SQL Empty Output

Tags: gdal, sql, ogr, sql-server-spatial

I have a Powershell script that loops through a database and outputs the spatial tables into another database in GDA2020 datum. I see one particular table is outputting but is empty. This table should have over 330000 rows. Is there a limit of rows OGR can handle or is there something I can add to the script to handle this, or could it be due to this table having multiple geometry types. Here is the script in OGR to make it clearer.

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs "+proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +wktext +nadgrids=C:\Program Files\MapManager35\ProjLib\GDA94_GDA2020_conformal.gsb" -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +wktext" -f "MSSQLSPATIAL" "MSSQL:driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=blahblah;Database=DestinationTable;Trusted_Connection=Yes" "MSSQL:driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=blahblah;Tables=dbo.SourceTable;Database=blahblah;Trusted_Connection=Yes" -nln outputtable
```

Comment: what sort of database? does `ogrinfo` work for that table? what does it show?

Comment: Hi Ian. It's SQL Spatial to SQL Spatial. It contains all of the Council's asset data which is why it is so large. I tested this with ogrinfo and the first few features have corrupt data, which is probably why it doesn't go any further. I recall this happening before on another script. The error is 'Error 1: GetNextRawFeatures(): Corrupt data'. Could this be due to badly drawn polygons that self intersect?

Comment: Not much that can be done with a corrupt database except restore from a good backup

Comment: There are quite a few invalid geometries, where geometries self intersect. Apart from manually going through and fixing every single geometry is there an OGR command that can validate SQL geometries? I tried -makevalid but it looks like that is for shp files.

Comment: The `-makevalid` option on ogr2ogr https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html is not limited to any file format so it should work.

Comment: Every time I add it to my script I get errors, going through each layer with the same error
`Error reading blahblah: ERROR 1: [S0002][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.blahblah2'.(208)`
The blahblah is every layer as it loops and the invalid object name is always one particular layer being repeated.

It doesn't seem to matter where I place -makevalid.